# Number of max simultaneous threads is less than max-thread-pool-size

Tags: multithreading, glassfish, grizzly

I don't understand behavior of glassfish v3.1.2.

I run my java web-application with such glassfish thread-pool parameters:

- Class Name: com.sun.grizzly.http.StatsThreadPool
- Max Queue Size: 4096
- Max Thread Pool Size: 10
- Min Thread Pool Size: 10
- Idle Thread
- Timeout: 900

Then I send many requests to my servlet. The logic of my servlet is like this:

```
//do some action
Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
```

Netbeans profiler shows these results in threads window:
http://s8.postimage.org/5hupqk4ad/profiler.png

It seems that all 10 threads were created, but only 5 can run simultaneously.
Of course I want to use max number of threads simultaneously.

Can somebody explain such behavior and suggest how to fix it.

Tell me if you need more information.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check your client side, may be you have restrictions there.

Comment: really! the reason was in a client source code. There was a restriction on 5 connections to the server.

Comment: @Vitaly - Just curious, what was the client used and how was it configured to make a specific number of connections to the server?

Comment: @AndyDufresne - It was client application with Great Maps control (http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/). This control was getting tiles from my server app. And the number of simultaniuos threads for getting tiles was equals 5.